# Rebuilding MenuItem after changing caption

Tags: java, database, vaadin

I've added MenuItem to my MenuBar in my app. Problem is that in MenuItem constructor I am setting a caption which is taking from database. While working with app this value is changing, but stay the same on my MenuItem. It's change only when I clear the session.
My question is: how to refresh it after every change? Is it possible?

Comment: How is the value changing, in the DB or within the application runtime objects?

Comment: Value is changing when you add something in some panel (because this panel is saving it to database). But this panel is used by different user (adding something like alerts to another users).

Comment: You could use [push and broadcast](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html#advanced.push.pusharound) the changes to the other users...

Comment: I don't know if it is not too much. Because I just want to change one value (for example when someone add some notification, I am increasing this value). But user (if he's log in) will see this new number after log out and log in.

Comment: You can either push a change when you react to an event such as your counter being increased when a new notification is added, or poll every once in a while to see if there are any changes. Other than these 2 cases I don't see how you could do it, so your options are rather limited. Think about it and any restrictions you may have, then make a decision.

Comment: Reacting to an event is good idea, but MenuItem don't have a change listener, so how to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry if I have not been specific enough. My idea of reacting to an event, in your case the counter change, is based on my initial suggestion. When your counter changes, by a button click or whatever, broadcast a message to all the other application instances that they need to update the menu caption. The other option I was mentioning, is to poll every 5 minutes (for example) from the application, and see if the counter value changed. If it did, then update the menu caption.

Comment: Thanks for help! I'll change the value after button click at every active session. I think its the best way.

Comment: No problem. Cool, after you do that please consider posting your implementation as an answer, and choosing it as the correct one after a couple of days, so people having similar problems can benefit from it as well. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Morfic I resolve this problem. 
I took the map of all active sessions, then iterate on this finding only those sessions in which values I'd like to update. Then just use the method of MenuItem - setText() and put there a new value.

Everything of this I putted on Save button.